# RestEasy + Jackson and JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: java, jboss, jackson, redhat, resteasy

I'm having a hard time getting a simple HelloWorld solution on JBOSS EAP 6.4 due to  version conflicts and dependencies.

I need to expose a REST API on a JBOSS EAP 6.4 server. Does anyone know of a good starting point for this that is out of the box compatible? I tried using this [guide](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/integrate-jackson-with-resteasy/) without success. I believe this is due to some versions that are shipped out of the box with the AS that I must use ([compatible versions](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673)).

What should my POM and WEB.XML contain so that I can develop a solution for JBOSS EAP using RestEasy + Jackson? Does anyone know where to find a HelloWorld example that works with EAP 6.4 e not just EAP 7?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem you are running into is library/classloader conflicts, add a `<scope>provided</scope>` to all the dependencies in your pom.xml that you know JBoss already provides and they will not be included in your WAR.

If you wish to ignore JBoss libraries/modules and specify your own (which is usually a pain) you have to introduce in your deployable, JBoss specific xml files that instruct the app server to not provide it's own libraries.

see: https://www.baeldung.com/resteasy-tutorial (jboss-deployment-structure)